# Calculate the percentage of Overlap between Convex Hull (ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, dplyr, overlap

I want to know if it is possible to know the percentage of overlap between convex hulls? For example, what is the % overlap between species Versicolor and Virginica?

The code I used for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
iris
find_hull <- function(iris) iris[chull(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width), ]
hulls <- ddply(iris, "Species", find_hull)
plot<-ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour=Species, fill = Species)) +geom_point() +geom_polygon(data = hulls, alpha = 0.5) 
plot
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Got it. I have edited the question.

Comment: There is `gIntersects` from the `rgeos` package